# Saving data from flash using amfphp!

Tags: database, flash, save, amfphp

I know how to get the data from my database, but i can't seem to figure out how to send data to the database from flash using amfphp!Please give me an as3 and php service example.Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

No problem, the docs page on amfphp lists an easy example sending "Hello World" to the web server, at which point you can use PHP normally to store the data in database of your choosing.  The link to that page is here:

http://www.amfphp.org/docs/testingamfphp.html